# sap.ui.table - FilterType on Column not working

Tags: sapui5

The filterType property of `sap.ui.table.Column` does not appear to work for me. Here is my code:

```
<table:Column sortProperty="abc" filterProperty="abc" filterType="sap.ui.model.type.Integer">  
    <table:label>  
        <Label text="abc"></Label>  
    </table:label>  
    <table:template>  
        <Label text="{modelName>abc}"></Label>  
    </table:template>  
</table:Column>
```

abc is containing a number as a string e.g. "10". The values are showing in the table so the bindings are correct.

Sorting also works but it does not respect the Integer type. I still get a String like sorting so that the entry "6" shows after "10" for an ascending sort. The column is even returning the filterType I set if I do sap.ui.getCore().byId("columnId").getFilterType(); What the heck is wrong here?

BR
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finally answer this: The filterType is NOT taken into account for sorting, no matter which view type you use. If you also think there should be a way to easily influence the sort logic you can support the issue here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/192

Answer (score 1):

It is working for the code snippet. You can click the column header to sort by descending or ascending and filter value.Please check.

```html
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.viz" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"></script>

<script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:table="sap.ui.table" controllerName="my.own.controller" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

        <table:Table id="testTable" rows="{/}">
            <table:Column sortProperty="abc" filterProperty="abc" filterType="sap.ui.model.type.Integer">
                <table:label>
                    <Label text="abc"></Label>
                </table:label>
                <table:template>
                    <Label text="{abc}"></Label>
                </table:template>
            </table:Column>
            <table:Column>
                <table:label>
                    <Label text="abc2"></Label>
                </table:label>
                <table:template>
                    <Label text="{abc2}"></Label>
                </table:template>
            </table:Column>
        </table:Table>
    </mvc:View>
</script>


<script>
    sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
        onInit: function() {
            var aTableData = [{
                abc: 1,
                abc2: "a"
            }, {
                abc: 6,
                abc2: "b"

            }, {
                abc: 10,
                abc2: "c"

            }, {
                abc: 3,
                abc2: "g"

            }, {
                abc: 12,
                abc2: "h"

            }];
            var oTableModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oTableModel.setData(aTableData);

            var oTable = this.getView().byId("testTable");
            oTable.setModel(oTableModel);
            oTable.sort(oTable.getColumns()[0]);
        }


    });

    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("myView", {
        viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
    }); // 
    myView.placeAt('content');
</script>

</head>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: hi cschuff, i changed it to XML view. It is working. Please check.

Comment: You can remove the filterType and it will also work. This is because your abc values are numbers. I'm talking about strings. Change abc values to string and you will see how the sorting is wrong.